# Characterizing continuous functions from $N$ with discrete metric into $R$ with absolute value metric

Tags: real-analysis

How can we characterize all continuous functions from $N$ with the discrete metric into $R$ with the absolute value metric?

I'm not sure what the question is asking. Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: Basically, what information can you gain about a function if all you know is that it is a continuous $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the given metrics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are asked for a characterisation, you need to state conditions that are equivalent to what is given or at least imply them or are implied by them.

Any function from $\mathbb N$ with the discrete metric to $\mathbb R$ with the absolute value metric will be continuous! This is because at any point $x$ in the domain, for any $\epsilon>0$, $d(x,y)<1$ implies that $x=y$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)|=0<\epsilon$.

Comment: Is it sufficient to show the case when $x=y$, or would I need to show when they are not equal as well?

Comment: Ohh okay, I got a little confused with the quantifiers. I see what you mean now, thanks!

Comment: Alternatively: a function is continuous iff the inverse image of every open subset of the target space is open in the domain. But *this* domain has the property that every subset is open. Thus every function is continuous.